# How to clodr (A).exe before running (B).exe

Tags: windows, exe, shortcut-file

I'd like to have a clickable file on my desktop that has the logic:

```
if (A.exe = running) {close A.exe}

run B.exe
```

So basically just checking if A.exe is running, and closing it before running B.exe

I'm generally familiar with coding, but really don't know where to begin with this, even language wise. Any advice appreciated, thank you!

Comment: *"suspend"* != *"close"*. If you are failing to explain that part of the problem that should be obvious to you, you're probably not the one to choose the best answer.

Comment: Is there a place to ask questions like this where they are more accepting of the non-willful ignorant? I just want to know how to close an .exe before running another .exe with a single click.

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify what you're asking. As @IInspectable pointed out, your title says "suspend", but your question body and your comment both indicate you're actually asking about "closing" an application, not "suspending" one. Also, a desktop shortcut can't do anything but launch a program; it can't implement logic to close one process if it's open. You can write an app or a script to do that and then call that app or script from a desktop shortcut.

Comment: Thanks Ken. I have edited my original question, but either way have now found a solution that works for me using a python script. Just had to brush the dust off of my already limited coding knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly I was overthinking this. To suit my need, I wrote a simple python script. There was no real need to check if A.exe was running in my case.

```
import os
import time

os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM A.exe")

os.startfile("C:\Program Files (x86)\B.exe")
```

To fancy it up a bit, I created a Windows desktop shortcut that pointed to the script and changed the icon to something more suitable than the python logo.

Comment: This doesn't really close A. It terminates it. Any unsaved data in A will probably be lost.